Do any three (or more) real numbers belong to some arithmetic progression?
I was solving a related question and thought of this. What I mean by the question is does there exist an arithmetic progession of which the three (or more) numbers are a part of. For example $2, 5, 9$ belong to the same arithmetic progression $2, 3, 4, \ldots, 9$. I got stuck when I tried to think of an arithmetic progression which contains $e, \pi, 25$. I am unable to find any arithmetic progression of which they are a part of, but I can't see why they shouldn't belong to some arithmetic progression. Is it true in general that any three (or maybe even more) real numbers belong to some arithmetic progression? I know that any number of rational numbers do belong to some arithmetic progression.

You might want to specify that the numbers must be distinct.

Consider two natural numbers and one non-algebraic: Would seem a contradiction?

If $a_n = a + nd$, i.e. is an arithmetic progression, then
$$\frac{a_i - a_j}{a_k - a_l} = \frac{i-j}{k-l} \in \mathbb Q$$
so there are clearly some limitations - not every sequence of numbers can be embedded in an arithmetical progression.
If you want to come up with a precise test, since you can always add some common number, like $\sqrt \pi$, to all the terms, it's best to just consider the "re-based" sequence, $\{a_n - a_0\}_{n = 0}^{\infty}$. There must be some number that these are all non-negative integral multiples of, which would probably be described as "being commensurable". And we can test that by dividing them.
So I won't write out all the details, but you can see that if your values are $b_0, b_2, ...., b_n$, then one examines the values
$$\frac{b_i-b_0}{b_1-b_0}$$
and checks that they are all non-negative, rational, and increasing. (Although as RobertIsrael comments, it's not always easy to check if a number is rational - combinations of $e$ and $\pi$ are frequently beyond our current knowledge.)
You'll have to do a bit of common denominator finding to explicitly specify the parameters of the desired arithmetic progression, but that's pretty easy.

As my cursor was on the "post answer" button!

I switched to my desktop from my phone! This "fastest gun" thing is challenging.

BTW, we have no proof that $\dfrac{e - 25}{\pi - 25}$ is irrational, though it's almost certainly true.

In linear algebraic terms, a finite set of real numbers fits into an arithmetic sequence iff its affine span over $\mathbb{Q}$ has dimension $\leqslant 1$.
